# Any.do done list

Tags: iphone, applications

I have iphone 5c and any.do. The done tasks are shown at the bottom of "today" grayed out and taking up space. I can delete them  but it seems very permanent, there's no way to look at them later?! Is there any way to archive them without permanently deleting them?

Answer (score 1):

You can shake the phone to archive all of the done tasks, they are then moved to the archive. You can then access them from `Settings -> Done Tasks`